# is there any performance gain in using latest PHP syntax?

Tags: php, syntax

With the latest release of PHP 5.4.x soon to be 5.5, there has been quite a few [new syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) introduce. I understand their significance in terms of code readability, less(er) typing by programmer, bug fixes etc.

But I am particularly keen on knowing how significant (if any) improvement in performance in terms of using these new syntax. Does the PHP interpreter and/or the Zend engine perform faster/better if more of the new syntax are used??

Or may be I am missing the whole point. Need your expertise knowledge and thoughts on this. Thank you!

Comment: Actually this is a good question as PHP is an interpreted (as opposed to compiled) language. So it highly depends on the interpreters implementation I guess.

Comment: Because it's classical example of the premature optimization question.

Comment: An evaluation for choice the development environment is premature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New syntax is added to a language to make writing the program easier and make the code easier to organise; not generally to make it perform any better. You shouldn't be thinking of using a specific syntax for performance reasons, but because it makes your code better, easier to work with, easier to read, etc.

For instance, PHP 5.5 introduces "Generator" syntax (the `yield` keyword). This is an improved way of writing Iterators. But it won't provide any performance difference between writing the Iterator-style code; it'll basically be doing the same thing under the hood. The important point is that it is much easier to write a simple Generator than writing the same code using an Iterator. The code is shorter, neater and easier to understand. It won't run any faster, but it will be much easier to work with. That's the whole point.

However, PHP does have a good track record of significantly improving performance in the language with every release. You don't even need to use the new features -- just upgrade to the latest version, and you'll get a performance boost from your existing code. In some cases, performance can improve by 50% or more. Given that, the upgrade should be a no-brainer; being able to use the new language features is an added bonus on top of the performance gains.

There are plenty of benchmarks out there to prove it; [here's one example](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/php-5-4-benchmarks) that covers PHP v5.1 through to 5.4.

(I haven't seen a good benchmark for v5.5 yet, presumably because it's still being worked on, but you can be sure benchmarks will be published soon after it's released)

Comment: So new syntax usage does not mean improved performance but rather it is the interpreter doing the dirty work. And it just so happens that latest releases comes packages together with new syntax to help with development rather. Thank you for this!

Comment: @shawndreck - yep, I've added an example relevant to 5.5 to demonstrate the point.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 0):

This is a system independent question.  Your mileage may vary based on what environment you're running on.  With that said, there isn't a definitive way to say whether or not its "faster".  To test your specific environment, you'd have to do some code profiling and see what the execution times are of some 5.4 code samples versus 5.5 code samples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I doubt using the new syntax adds any significant improvements. The parser might parse the terser new syntax quicker but it generates much the same op codes it did with an older version. Meaning the improvements here are hardly noticeable.

On the other hand the new versions have improvements in the internal workings which means that both the older and the newer code runs better on the newer engine